# Paypal Standard return update not completing

Tags: contributions, ipn

Joomla 3.5.1
CiviCRM 4.7.7
Contribution Page setup with Paypal as payment processor.
Page completes, Payment completes in Paypal.  Paypal sends confirmation Email.
Paypal shows IPN record. Shows status of 200 (OK?)
Contribution payment is not updated to completed, membership remains in pending (as expected) and no email from CiviCRM goes out to member.
If I add and use the paylater option the email from CiviCRM goes out to the member.  First noticed this in March April time frame with an event.

In joomla looking at most recent log in ConfigAndLog under Media/civicrm

```
msg > We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enabled in your browser settings. Please check this setting and enable cookies (if they are not enabled). Then try again. If this error persists, contact the site administrator for assistance.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Site Administrators: This error may indicate that users are accessing this page using a domain or URL other than the configured Base URL. EXAMPLE: Base URL is http://example.org, but some users are accessing the page via http://www.example.org or a domain alias like http://myotherexample.org.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Error type: Could not find a valid session key.

#1 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(833): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("We can't load the requested web page. This page requires cookies to be enable...")
#2 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(853): CRM_Core_Controller->invalidKeyCommon()
#3 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Controller/Contribution.php(74): CRM_Core_Controller->invalidKeyRedirect()
#4 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(312): CRM_Contribute_Controller_Contribution->invalidKey()
#5 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(204): CRM_Core_Controller->key("CRM_Contribute_Controller_Contribution", TRUE, FALSE)
#6 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Controller/Contribution.php(55): CRM_Core_Controller->__construct("CiviContribute", "null")
#7 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(307): CRM_Contribute_Controller_Contribution->__construct("CiviContribute", TRUE, "null", NULL, "false")
#8 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#9 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#10 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(90): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#11 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(11): civicrm_invoke()
#12 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(405): require_once("/home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm...")
#13 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(380): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/components/com_civicrm/civicrm...")
#14 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#15 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/libraries/cms/application/site.php(230): JApplicationSite->dispatch()
#16 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(257): JApplicationSite->doExecute()
#17 /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/index.php(49): JApplicationCms->execute()
#18 {main}
```

Comment: Nothing showing up in the civicrm system log table either.  Last entry for a payment there was end of March 2016

Answer (score 1):

If PayPal is saying the IPN went through correctly, it's worth checking to see what the URL PayPal is using for the IPN.  Does it match what you're expecting?  Can you find your Apache (or nginx) web server logs and correlate them with PayPal?  Are they also showing a 200?  Or perhaps a redirect of some sort?

Comment: https://www.isfpta.org/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/extern/ipn.php (and more details).   We moved to https: several years ago.  Checking Apache logs.

Comment: I have looked through our web usage and web error logs viewable through PHPAdmin.  The error log has a considerable number of PHP Notice(s).  One that shows up repeatedly is:  Array to string conversion in /home/isfptaadm/domains/isfpta.org/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/ContributionBase.php on line 650.  I don't think it relates to the IPN transaction as the referring site is our schools.  I am inclined to think this happens as our schools site calls our site's civicrm contribution page.

Comment: @DonaldKnapp Besides the errors - can you confirm that you're seeing 200 (success) HTTP codes for requests to the IPN page?

Comment: here is one.   173.0.81.1 - - [19/May/2016:07:31:36 +0800] "POST /components/com_civicrm/civicrm/extern/ipn.php?reset=1&contactID=5685&contributionID=8429&module=contribute&membershipID=3941 HTTP/1.1" 200 44877 "-" "PayPal IPN ( https://www.paypal.com/ipn )"

Comment: Next line is this:  45.64.241.218 - - [19/May/2016:07:32:11 +0800] "GET /index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contribute/transact&Itemid=1954&_qf_ThankYou_display=1&qfKey=.........

Comment: There are 9 more messages in the log from the ip addr ending 218.   All are 200s except the second to last one which is a 302.                      112.119.92.55 - - [19/May/2016:12:32:23 +0800] "POST /index.php?option=com_users&task=reset.request HTTP/1.1" 302 3565 "https://www.isfpta.org/index.php?option=com_users&view=reset" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586"

Comment: Any other thoughts? @Jon G

Comment: @DonaldKnapp Sorry, I think I'm at the limit of what I can troubleshoot from here.