# Thank you page not loading after payment

Tags: wordpress, paypal, recurring-contributions, session, cookies

I have a new WordPress site with CiviCRM installed. I'm testing recurring payments using PayPal, but a problem  occurs after the payment has been made. The browser tries to return to the site/merchant, but never succeeds. Eventually after 1 minute or so it fails/gives up.

Also the payment is still taken from the buyer, and their membership is activated. The buyer wouldn't know this unless they checked their email so might try to pay again before checking emails.

I've checked the log file but I don't understand it too well because I'm not a programmer. Although there are some warnings about a propertyBag.

Anyone experience a similar problem or know what might be causing it?

Thanks,

Monica.

---

**Update:**

When using the civicrm link rather than embedded shortcode, the user is returned to the site after payment, but the page says the session has expired. I've researched this and the solutions are that "This has been fixed in the next version of civicrm" meaning it must be fixed in my version too since those posts I researched were old. I've tried clearing cookies and that didn't work. Also tried with my caching plugin disabled. Still no joy.

I will reinstall civicrm and start from scratch instead.

[image: session expired]

```
Jun 26 11:40:38  [warning] Civi\Payment\PropertyBag related deprecation warnings:
We have merged input params into the property bag for now but please rewrite code to not use this.
Unknown property 'qfKey'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'entryURL'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'hidden_processor'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'email-5'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'payment_processor_id'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'auto_renew'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'priceSetId'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'price_19'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'MAX_FILE_SIZE'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'ip_address'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'amount'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'selectMembership'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
We have translated 'currencyID' to 'currency' for you, but please update your code to use the propper setters and getters.
Unknown property 'is_pay_later'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
We have translated 'is_recur' to 'isRecur' for you, but please update your code to use the propper setters and getters.
We have translated 'frequency_interval' to 'recurFrequencyInterval' for you, but please update your code to use the propper setters and getters.
We have translated 'frequency_unit' to 'recurFrequencyUnit' for you, but please update your code to use the propper setters and getters.
Unknown property 'is_quick_config'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'contributionType_name'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'contributionType_accounting_code'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'contributionPageID'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'receive_date'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'createdMembershipIDs'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Unknown property 'membershipID'. We have merged this in for now as a custom property. Please rewrite your code to use PropertyBag->setCustomProperty if it is a genuinely custom property, or a standardised setter like PropertyBag->setContactID for standard properties
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)
```

Comment: can you include civi and cms version

Comment: not getting returned from paypal? does this relate? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11828/paypal-standard-return-update-not-completing

Comment: is your paypal account the type where the purchaser is sent off to PayPal, or does it all happen on the civi screen?

Comment: @PradeepNayak civi version is 5.25.0 wordpress is 5.4.2

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I'm using paypal standard where the user gets sent off the the paypal site. I don't feel the link you posted relates. The link relates to Joomla and is quite old. Also in my situation the membership does get activated.... sometimes!

Comment: CMS will be irrelevant. try some other answers here maybe https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/search?q=paypal+ipn

Comment: @petednz-fuzion ah yes you're right it shouldn't matter because the error is probably with PayPal or civi.

Comment: The API seems to be working because I did a live test and the membership renewed automatically via paypal this morning. The live test also did not redirect to the thank you page but membership got activated automatically. 


`Google
This page <website domain> redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
-------------
Firefox
An error occurred during a connection to <website domain>.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.n sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.`

Comment: have you done all steps per https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/paypal-standard/

Comment: Thank you yes I have double checked the payment processor info again and have the correct info including auto return url. The redirect process does seem to take a long time to try to work before it fails - maybe like 30-50 seconds, so maybe it's timing out and that's why the session expires. Is there any way of keeping the session open longer?
The hosting support will get back to me soon about enabling the trigger privilege for the db user so that I can reinstall civicrm and start from scratch. This wasn't disabled before so not sure what happened in the last few weeks.